# Unable to start HyperV VM with Minkube for Kubernetes Cluster for spark in windows 10

Tags: kubernetes, hyper-v, minikube, hypervisor

I am trying to create a Kubernetes cluster on Windows with the help of Minikube and Hyperv. I tried below things:
1) I have enabled HyperV after following this [blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v) from Microsoft.I confirmed it using `systeminfo` command and it shows that `hypervisor is detected`.

2) I ran `minikube start --vm-driver=hyperv` in admin mode but facing below error:

```
* Suggestion: Start PowerShell as Administrator, and run: 'Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All'
* Documentation: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/reference/drivers/hyperv/

X hyperv does not appear to be installed
```

3) I also tried creating virtual switch for hyperv and using this command `minikube start --vm-driver=hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch="hypervswitch"`but no luck. I also tried `minikube start --alsologtostderr -v=7` and I can see from the below logs that hyperv is not installed.

```
status for hyperv: {Installed:false Healthy:false Error:C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-All -Online failed:
```

**Note**: I am running each and every command in admin mode. I am not sure what is the problem.

I referred the official github issues blog for my issue but didn't help. Can anyone help me over here? I am stuck since days..

Comment: Did you enable hyperv with shell or through settings? If it was through shell could you please check if it's enabled like in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v?redirectedfrom=MSDN#enable-the-hyper-v-role-through-settings)?  Because `X hyperv does not appear to be installed` say's that it wasn't installed. There is [github issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2181#issuecomment-344916328) with the hyperv-switch, and there is the answer with 21 upvotes, could you try this and let me know if it worked?

Comment: I tried everything but didn't work.

Comment: Can anyone suggest something over here?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, adding `--force` worked for me:

```
minikube start --vm-driver=hyperv --force
```